# Mongoose Multiple Level Populate with Refpath

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to use Mongoose populate() feature with a nested path but WITH refpath:

Child schema:

```
let child = new Schema({
  item: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    refPath: "itemType",
  },
  itemType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["typeA", "typeB"],
  },
});
```

Parent schema:

```
let parent = new Schema({
  children: [child],
});
```

After building my models, I run a query:

```
let mQuery1 = Parent.find().populate({
  /* Type 1, does not populate at all. */ path: "children",
  populate: { path: "item" },
});
```

This just does nothing.

```
let mQuery2 = Parent.find().populate({
  path: "children",
  populate: [
    { path: "item", model: "typeA" },
    { path: "item", model: "typeB" },
  ],
});
```

And this query ends up populating one type of the fields and the others not(e.g, populates typeA and returns null for typeB(s)).

So my question is, how do I come about populating nested fields that utilise refPath?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer, thought I would share

you won't need to populate model like this:

```
<br>
let mQuery2 = Parent.find().populate({<br>
  path: "children",<br>
  populate: [<br>
    { path: "item", model: "typeA" },<br>
    { path: "item", model: "typeB" },<br>
  ],<br>
});<br>
```

but just:

```
<br>
let mQuery2 = Parent.find().populate({ <br>
  path: "children", populate: <br>
    {path: "item"}<br>
})<br>
```

However, in your posting route, you must have **itemType** with the value of either typeA or typeB. The respective model will then be populated automatically. I also managed to pass the chosen model to the **itemType** automatically on the backend only so no one needs to manually key in the model name.

here's the link that has helped me with this issue:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7273

Answer (score 0):

As I found in [the github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7273) provided by @Yandy, you have a logical error in the refPath, your child schema is valid, but when you add it inside the parent schema you have to change the refPath property of `child.item` to be `children.itemType`, after this your first query will run just fine!.

Full example:

```
const parent = new Schema({
  children: [{
  item: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    refPath: "children.itemType",
  },
  itemType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["typeA", "typeB"],
  },
}],
});
```

And your query should be like this:

```
Parent.find().populate({
  path: "children",
  populate: { path: "item" },
});
```